# highcharts open duplicate map in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Does anyone know how to open a highcharts map in a modal? I want to load the page, have a chart displayed then on click open it in the modal. I have that working, but on click of the chart in the modal, the chart printed on page load updates and the chart in the modal does not.

Comment: Look at this thread on Highcharts forum and check if it follows your needs: https://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?t=34967

Comment: I saw that page, that does not work because I need it to have the js tied to it as well. For now I am appending to and removing it from the dom when its in the modal and that works.